# Philip Phillip Philips Phillips - Etymology

Tags: etymology

Is there any reason for these four different spellings of what seem to be a very similar name? (One 'l' vs double 'l'; and 's' vs no 's')

Comment: Originally Philip, it may have variants (Phillips) especially as a surname: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_(name)

Comment: William Shakespeare's name was spelled a [couple dozen different ways](http://shakespeareauthorship.com/name1.html) even during his lifetime. Can we expect any better for the Phil(l)ip(p)(s)es?

Comment: Also Philipsson a very popular Swedish last name/surname  http://lastnames.myheritage.it/last-name/philipsson

Comment: @Mari As are _Phillipsson_, _Filipsson_, _Fillipsson_, and possibly even _Philipson_, _Phillipson_, _Filipson_, and _Fillipson_ (though the one you linked to is by far the most common). In neighbouring Danish, at least, all eight variations are perfectly unremarkable (substituting _-sen_ for _-son_), though the ones with double s, by far the most common in Swedish, would be by far the least common in Danish.

Answer (score 2):

*Phillip* (along with its alternate spellings) comes from the Greek *Philippos*, meaning "lover of horses." Spelling was quite fluid for most words in general until around the 18th century, because there weren't many dictionaries and most people were illiterate anyway. The spelling of most words became standardized as the written word proliferated, but proper names didn't experience the same pressure to regularize--your name was yours and no one could tell you how you had to spell it, so spelling differences persisted.

*Phillips* as a surname probably originated as a [patronymic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic), like my surname (*Henry*, anglicized from *Heinrich* in the 1700s). The *s* could have been tacked on in any number of ways, and probably happened multiple times in various ways for different Phillips families, as well as for the single-*l* variety (see e.g. [Royal Philips Electronics](http://www.philips.com/), founded by Dutch industrialist Gerard Philips).

Comment: Added a paragraph about *Phillips* as a surname--thanks.

Comment: http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Philipson *Philips* a shortened form of *Philipson*? And with a double-p too! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippson And lets not forget Philippa :)

Comment: English has the word *philhippic* meaning “fond of or interested in horses” (NB: horses, not hippies :), where the etymology may be more apparent than in *Φίλιππος*.

Comment: I know of one person with "Phillips" as a forename - Phillips Idowu, former world triple-jump champion. Incidentally, I'm a Philip, which I regard as the correct spelling (of course!).